# StackOverFlow Exception I don't get why?

Tags: c#, .net

```
//something is wrong with Parents setter property idk what :C, 
//i'm getting an exception when third ctor executes...

class Person     {
        public string Name { get;set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<Person> Parents { get { return (Person[])Parents; } 
private set { Parents = value; } } // I'm getting StackOverFlow here BUT WHY ?

        public Person(string Name,DateTime DateOfBirth,Person[] parents=null)
        {
            this.Name = Name;this.DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth;Parents = parents;
        }
    }
    // Main class
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Creating 3 objects and get exception on third
            Person prs = new Person("Emily", DateTime.Now, null);
            Person prss = new Person("mark", DateTime.Now);
            Person psrs = new Person("maras", DateTime.Now, new[] { prs, prss });

            if (psrs.Parents != null)
            {
                foreach (var parent in psrs.Parents)              
                    Console.WriteLine();               
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("No parents");
        }
    }
```

// question in addition : Is my class realization comply all principles of OOP ?
//okay maybe it's becouse in constructor and property i do exactly the same thing but if i would remove Parent = parents in ctor how could i initializate my Parents property via constructor ? also if i remove my set propery i can't initialize Parents property. Help please !

Comment: `Parents` is self referencing.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344909/stackoverflow-exception-i-dont-get-why)

Comment: Post does not include [MCVE] - code shown is not minimal. (In addition to asking question that asked and answered tons of time already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Parents` property is setting itself inside the `setter`. You need to have an appropriate backing field.

```
private IEnumerable<Person> _parents
public IEnumerable<Person> Parents 
{ 
    get { return (Person[])_parents; } 
    private set 
    { 
        _parents = value; 
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
You can also just use an auto-property, as I do not see the need for a backing field.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Parents { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I would further point out it seems odd to cast  an IEnumerable to an array, only to return it as an IEnumerable.

Comment: Right. I updated the answer. He should only need an auto property.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! @d.moncada 
Now it's a lot more clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

As @crashmstr said, `Parents` is referencing itself.. Here's a bit of an explanation:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Parents 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return (Person[])Parents; 
    } 
    private set 
    { 
        Parents = value; 
    } 
}
```

When using C#, properties like this are essentially compiled into the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Parents_get()
{
    return (Person[])Parents.get();
}
public void Parents_set(IEnumerable<Person> value) 
{ 
    Parents_set(value);
}
```

Which makes it a lot clearer as to why it's self referencing.

You can simply define your property as:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Parents { get; set; }
```